# JAVASCRIPT - intercepting keycode 13 (enter) in dynamically-created editbox and passing element to different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok..I've been working all day on a demo CRUD app learning some Bootstrap and JS basics...
I've almost got what I want but the last thing is I need it to do is while in the editbox to grab the keycode 13 event (enter) and so send the right class to a function that already works..

it all goes something like this...

```
$(function() {
  ...
  ...
  $(document).on("blur", "input#editbox", function(){ saveEditable(this) });
});

 function saveEditable(element) { 

        $('#indicator').show();

        var User = new Object();
        User.id = $('.current').attr('user_id');        
        User.field = $('.current').attr('field');
        User.newvalue = $(element).val();

        var userJson = JSON.stringify(User);

        $.post('Controller.php',
            {
                action: 'update_field_data',            
                user: userJson
            },
            function(data, textStatus) {
                $('td.current').html($(element).val());
                $('.current').removeClass('current');
                $('#indicator').hide();         
            }, 
            "json"      
        );  
    }

function makeEditable(element) { 
        $(element).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+  $(element).text().length +'" type="text" value="'+ $(element).text() +'" onkeypress="return checkForEnter(event)">');  
        $('#editbox').focus();
        $(element).addClass('current'); 
}

function checkForEnter(e){

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            saveEditable(e);
            return false;
        }
}
```

It works pretty good on the blur event firing but just isn't quite there for ENTER

here is the link...just Load the table and see http://markenriquez.tekcities.com/credapp

advTHNAKSance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `event` as argument to  saveEditable() method from checkForEnter(). Wherein you should pass input field reference instead.

Try this,

```
    function checkForEnter(e){

            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                saveEditable(e.target);
                return false;


    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahhh...yeah of course after posting this I realized I was passing an event where an element was needed, so this is awesome now I know the target property of an event is its element :))  Worked like a charm BTW...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("keypress", "input#editbox",function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
      do_something();
   }
});
```

PS. Your textarea top-left and bottom-left corners are rounded.

Comment: yes i thought about something like this to begin with, but to be honest i wanted to learn something new :) thks for the tips